# In C, how do values from an array get inputted into a function?

Tags: c, arrays

I have been having difficulty with arrays in functions. I want the array1 in the main program loop to share the same value as array1 in the function, but am having severe difficulty. I understand this may be easy to some, but as a first year programming student problems like this are expected. Would appreciate the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int FillArray(int array1[9])
{

    int array1[9], array2[9], i, n=0;


    for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        if  (array1[i] > 0)
            array2[i] = array1[i] * 2;
            else
                array2[i] = array1[i] * 10;

        printf("\n%d", array2[10]);
    }
    return 0;
} /* End of FillArray Function */

int main()
{
    int array1[9] = { 40, 13, -5, 22, 10, 80, -2, 50, 9, -7 };
    FillArray(array1[9]);


}
```

Comment: You can pass the array in without the size in the parameter list. To keep things clear, you should use a different name in the function. (eg - int FillArrary(int someArray[]). Next what does the for loop do when n=0?

Comment: You have a local variable called `array1` which hides the paramater with the same name.  Get rid of the variable.

Comment: You should invoke the function FillArray like this `FillArray(array1);`

Comment: Also the for loop goes from 0 to 0, doing nothing

Comment: Changed the mistake in the code. The function is supposed to find out for every number in the array, which one is positive and which is negative then multiply by 2 or by 10 respectively. Then i need to have an array in the main program loop, which gives an array to input into the function.

Comment: This codfe is an error, you have 10 initializers for an array of size 9.  If the compiler doesn't give an error message then please check your compiler settings as it is important to see error messages for erroneous code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* don't need to specify size of array1 here */
/* rather pass the no. of elements of array1 through n*/

int FillArray(int array1[], int n) {
    /* observe, you've 10 elements in array1 */
    /* that's why array2[10] */
    /* size of array2 should be >= n */
    int array2[10], i;

    /* I replaced 9 with 10 as array1 */
    /* has n elements...ranges 0 to n-1 */
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if  (array1[i] > 0)
            array2[i] = array1[i] * 2;
        else
            array2[i] = array1[i] * 10;


        /* I didn't get this below line. */
        /* Should it be outside the loop? or what you've tried to do here. */
        /* If you want to print the content of array2,*/
        /* then see your book how to print an array */
        /* for an array of size n,*/
        /*it's index range is 0 to n-1.....so 10 is not valid */

        // printf("\n%d", array2[10]); // this line
    }


    /* To print array2, in case if you want to know about it */
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    /* you don't have to specify size here */
    /* but again, if you would like to specify */
    /* it would be >= 10 as you've at least 10 elements in array1 */
    int array1[] = { 40, 13, -5, 22, 10, 80, -2, 50, 9, -7 };
    /* it's good habit to pass the no. of elements of an array */
    FillArray(array1, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the fillarray() the printing statement is not valid. array2[10] is not a valid range as the loop will run upto 9. So make it less or equal to 9.  It will be like this

```
array2[i]
```

Or you can write it as

```
array2[9]
```

And you can pass the array1[] in the main function as an parameter. You need to rewrite it like this

```
int main(int array1[])
```

Or you can do this in the main function

```
Int main()
{ 
     /* Write what you want /*
      array1[] = { _the_values_you_want to_give}
      fillarray(array1)
```

Hope this will help